# Is it possible to buy multiple hardware MFA devices with the same key?

Tags: multi-factor, aws

I would like to secure an AWS root account with a hardware MFA device, which seems to be simple enough, but I also want a backup device to store in a different location. AWS doesn't seem to support multiple MFA devices on the same account, but if I could get a synchronized pair of MFA devices they would effectively be a single device to AWS.

Is it possible to buy pairs of such devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can buy hardware devices, that can be seeded like the Yubikey, the etoken pass or some Feitian tokens.
Thus you can put the same seed provided by AWS on multiple hardware devices.

Comment: Any documentation available on how to do that?
My objective is to use an hardware MFA in AWS console to pass CIS.1.14 
(The root user is the most privileged user in an AWS account. MFA adds an extra layer of protection on top of a user name and password. With MFA enabled, when a user signs in to an AWS website, they will be prompted for their user name and password as well as for an authentication code from their AWS MFA device. For Level 2, it is recommended that the root user be protected with a hardware MFA)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the virtual one, you can print the QR code and/or write down the secret. Multiple Google Authenticators can scan the same code, or you can type it in manually to Google Authenticator.